# jquery regexp - HTML tag from string

Tags: javascript, regex

how can I separate a HTML table tag from string by using regular expression?

```
var sTabString =' ... <table > <table ... any string ... id="Unique_1"  ... any string ...> abc def <table > ... ';
var sReg = '< *table .* id *= *"Unique_1" .*>';
var sRegEx = new RegExp(sReg);
var sResult = sTabString .match(sRegEx);
alert(sResult);
```

I expect the open tag with all its attributes as follows:

```
<table ... any string ... id="Unique_1"  ... any string ...>
```

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you need to do this?

Comment: I agree with @h2ooooooo - I wanted to link XY problem as well. Tell us what are you trying to achieve, because we are 98% sure you're not going to need regex for your task.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I changed it to that as it was confusing. As far as I can understand given the string `<table id="foo" class="table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Hi</th></tr></thead></table>` he wants `<table id="foo" class="table-bordered">` (the *open tag*).

Comment: can you post the full table code and tell us what you want to be extracted ?

Comment: I'm trying to read certain HTML tables from text.

Comment: From text? Not from HTML source? It's really hard to propose a solution. We don't know where this HTML comes from and why can't you use DOM traversing.

Comment: @user3417601 Convert it to an element by surrounding it by `$(htmlText)` and then use `.find()` to get your rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Javascript RegExp to find opening tags in HTML/php template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038235/create-a-javascript-regexp-to-find-opening-tags-in-html-php-template)

Answer (score 1):

This will get you every `<table>` element (and all its attributes) in a string.

```
var regex = new RegExp("<table.*?>", "g");

var result = str.match(regex);  

for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++)
{
    // do something with your <table> elements here
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```